# Can't scroll main window with curses

Tags: ruby, curses

I just faced the same problem as this guy: http://computer-programming-forum.com/39-ruby/b4065fe9ccbcae86.htm

Curses (same as Window) have methods `scrl(n)` and `scroll()`, and to enable them I have to do `.scrollok true`. The problem is that unlike Window:

```
temp.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `scrollok' for Curses:Module (NoMethodError)
```

*I had to add a scrollok wrapper..... What good is having a scrl() wrapper if you can't enable scrolling in the first place?*

So is it a bug or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting the question I came up with a solution.

You don't have to make a wrapper. Just use [.scrollok](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-stdscr) in this way:

```
Curses.stdscr.scrollok true
```